# text box auto suggest with a huge array of 4000 using swift xcode

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a text box that also shows an an autosuggest in swift, however if the array list is very big xcode fails to compile the list

Comment: The compiler can choke on large array literals in the source code, this has been reported repeatedly, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755663/why-do-i-get-an-error-just-because-i-have-a-large-array-in-swift. – The proper solution however would be to load the list from a resource file, instead of defining a huge array literal in the source code.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, could you help me with an eg of loading the array from a resource file

Comment: Start with the (admittedly outdated) [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html).